# Add default values in multi-dimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays, where the first item is a simple labels array, and then the rest of the values are arrays which have first element the day number, and the second element number of views for that day. So in my bellow example I have 163 views for day 2 and 9 views for day 5.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Day' (length=3)
      1 => string 'Pageviews' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => int 163
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => int 9
```

What I want is to add 0 views for the days which don't appear in this array. So if I want to start from 1 to 18 day interval how can I create an array which has my views per day, and 0 views for the days which are not in my first array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out. The code bellow will get all associations in ascending order and with 0 as default value:

```
    $existingArray = 'my existing array';

    $existingDays = array_column($existingArray, 0);
    $existingViews = array_column($existingArray, 1);

    //I use this array to track relationships between days and views
    $bindings = array_combine($existingDays, $existingViews);

    $viewsData = array();
    $viewsData[0] = array('Day', 'Pageviews');

    for ($day = 1; $day <= 8; $day++) {
        $viewsNumber = (isset($bindings[$day])) ? $bindings[$day] : 0;
        $viewsData[] = array($day, $viewsNumber);
    }
    return $viewsData;
```

Answer (score 0):

### A single loop solution:

<s>I assume that each (array key + 1) is the day number. If so,</s> you can try with this approach:

```
$array = ... //your filled array
$existingDays = array();
$totalDays = 18;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalDays; $i++) {
    $existingDays[$array[$i][0]] = true;

    if (!array_key_exists($i, $existingDays)) {
        $array[$i] = array( (string)($i+1), 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Since you don't know the list of existing days you can create another array `$existingDays` and fill it with the proper day on each loop step. Notice:

- I fill the array with *keys*, not *values*. The reason for that is it is faster to check if a key exists in an array than checking if a value exists (`in_array()` function iterates over the whole array)
- as you said, days are ordered ascending, so we can simply add the day to the `$existingDays` array in the same loop, before we do the `if`. A single day number is **at least** the same as the current array key (but ussually greater) so there is no possibility to accidentially check the day that doesn't exist in the `$existingDays` **yet**.

Comment: Not really. I've edited my answer to a different values. Basically I fetch all the days in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick you are trying to achieve :

```
//storing the days present in the array
$days_present = array_column($input_array,0,0);

for($i=1; $i<32; $i++){
    //push if days are not present in the input array
    if(!array_key_exists($i, $day_present) )
        array_push($input_array,array($i,0) );
}
```